# Django Rest Framework batch requests

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I am trying to make a batch endpoint in Django Rest Framework, in the spirit of Google's [batch requests](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/batch). To do that, the endpoint uses `TokenAuthentication` and asks for a json-encoded list of dictionaries with path, method and data if necessary, like this:

```
[
    {
        "path": "/endpoint1",
        "method": "GET"
    },
    {
        "path": "/endpoint2",
        "method": "GET"
    },
    {
        "path": "/endpoint3",
        "method": "POST",
        "data": {
            "file": "<base64>"
        }
    }
]
```

The view iterates the list, copies the request (with the token), sets path and method according to each item and gets a response by resolving the path. Here's the code:

```
from copy import copy

@api_view(["POST"])
@authentication_classes((SessionAuthentication, TokenAuthentication))
@permission_classes((IsAuthenticated,))
def batch(request):
    operations = request.data
    responses = []
    for operation in operations:
        op_request = copy(request._request)
        op_request.path = operation["path"]
        op_request.method = operation["method"]
        view, args, kwargs = resolve(operation["path"])
        response = view(op_request, *args, **kwargs)
        operation["response"] = {
            "status": response.status_code,
            "data": response.data
        }
    return Response(operations)
```

All the non-batch endpoints use the same `autentication_classes` and `permission_classes`. The problem I am coming across is that the authentications headers are not the same to the dispatched views. That is, the regular response for `/endpoint3` , when sending a file (with a user token) is a successful response:

```
{
    "id": "asdf",
    "name": "asdf.txt",
}
```

But when run in batch it ends like this:

```
[
    ...<other operations>...,
    {
        "response": {
            "status": 403,
            "data": {
                "detail": "CSRF Failed: CSRF cookie not set."
            }
        },
        "path": "/endpoint3",
        "method": "POST",
        "data": {
            "file": "<Base64>"
        }
    }
]
```

Am I passing the headers right to the new requests I am dispatching?

Comment: You know what `CSRF` means , don't You ?

Comment: @Take_Care_ I guess so. I forgot to add the `SessionAuthentication` in the decorator, I edited the question to add all the decorators needed. But still, it should not make different responses whether I am using the regular or the batch endpoint

Comment: Ok, so Your call to view is first pressed by `CsrfViewMiddleware` , it secures You against cross site reference attacks. If You want disable this protection for test proupose just set `_dont_enforce_csrf_checks` cookie to `True`.

Comment: and I guess the problem can just be with `copy` :P what result will You get if You use `deep_copy` ?  because the middle-ware is checking `request.META` and It can miss the needed values.

Comment: @Take_Care_ `TypeError: cannot serialize '_io.BufferedReader' object`.  I guess the files cannot be deep-copied.

Comment: So try to deepcopy just the Meta

Comment: @Take_Care_ The same error happens.